# Selenium IDE select window in loop?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I wrote a selenium script  that will open a specific URL to then click on button at the index page. After that, a pop up window will show up. The script will click on a button inside this new pop up window, so i need to select that window  in order to make a command on it.

So i did (select window) and give it the target (win_ser_1), which  belongs to the pop up window and it clicked the button. After that it  will select the previous index page (win_ser_local) and start over again and again until the loops end.

The problem is: when the selenium open a new pop up it gives it a target name like this (win_ser_1 ) and when it closes it and opens it again, the pop up will show with a different name (win_ser_2) although i closed the previews pop up before.

So it seems i need to give the select window a new value each time the selenium a open a pop up? If so, I will need to count how many times the script will open a pop up?! But i don't want this, so: is there a simple way fix this?

My commands:

[image]

Comment: In the kantu [selenium ide](https://a9t9.com/kantu) you can control tabs by _index_, so you can use [selectWindow | tab=x](https://a9t9.com/kantu/docs/selenium-ide/selectwindow) with x=1,2,3... that should make things easier.

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: i used kantu selenium ide , the problem solved by typing selectWindows title="the title of the pop up" but i faced another problem  ,there is no command to close the pop up in kantu